# Golang and DBUS

Tags: go, arm, dbus

I would like to convert this `Python` code in `Go`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import dbus

if (len(sys.argv) < 2):
    print("Usage: %s <modem> <ussd-string>" % (sys.argv[0]))
    sys.exit(1)

bus = dbus.SystemBus()
path = sys.argv[1]
ussdstring = sys.argv[2]

ussd = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object('org.ofono', path),
                      'org.ofono.SupplementaryServices')

properties = ussd.GetProperties()
state = properties["State"]

if state == "idle":
    result = ussd.Initiate(ussdstring, timeout=100)[1]
elif state == "user-response":
    result = ussd.Respond(ussdstring, timeout=100)
else:
    sys.exit(1);

properties = ussd.GetProperties()
state = properties["State"]
print('USSD RESPONSE:\n', result)
print('USSD SESSION:\n', state)
```

I made a try with the `github.com/guelfey/go.dbus` library:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/guelfey/go.dbus"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("DBUS Test.\n")
    conn, err := dbus.SessionBus()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Failed to connect to session bus:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    busObject := conn.Object("org.ofono", "/ril_0")
    fmt.Println("busObject:", busObject)
    var list []string
    busObject.Call("org.ofono.SupplementaryServices.Initiate", 0, "#101#").Store(&list)
    fmt.Println("list:", list)
    for _, v := range list {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

But I got the following response:

```
DBUS Test.
Failed to connect to session bus: user: Current not implemented on linux/arm
```

Do you know how to use this DBUS library? Is this library the best one for `go` on ARM7?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This particular problem is right in the error message:

> ... user: Current not implemented on linux/arm"

`user.Current` is only called for auth, so if you supply your own [`Auth`](https://godoc.org/github.com/guelfey/go.dbus#Auth) method it won't call `user.Current`.

It looks like you'll have to create your own conn though, instead of using the global `sessionBus`. (see the source of [`SessionBus`](https://godoc.org/github.com/guelfey/go.dbus#SessionBus) and [`Conn.Auth`](https://godoc.org/github.com/guelfey/go.dbus#Conn.Auth) for more details)

```
conn, err := dbusSessionBusPrivate()
if err != nil {
    return
}

auths := []dbus.Auth{dbus.AuthExternal(username), dbus.AuthCookieSha1(username, homedir)}
if err := conn.Auth(auths); err != nil {
    conn.Close()
    return
}
```

You could also patch `go.dbus` to use an alternative method for finding the username and homedir for arm, like checking `$USER` and `$HOME` (or file an issue, or open a pull request).

Comment: Thank you. The python code is working fine, without auth. How is this possible ?

Comment: @Julio: if auth isn't required, then don't call Auth. I don't know what the python library is doing implicitly.